# R Shiny: invoking Shiny.onInputChange via session$sendCustomMessage

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

I'm building a Shiny app that has a table where the user can select and highlight cells. When the user hits the go button, the app is supposed to send the positions of the user-selected cells to the server.

I'm hitting the wall with the client to server communication. Below is the minimum reproducible example--why doesn't it work?

```
library(shiny)

script <- '
    Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler("jsCode", function(message) { 
        eval(message.value);
    });
    function hello() {
        console.log("hello from function hello!");
    };
'

ui <- fluidPage(
    tags$head(tags$script(HTML(script))),
    actionButton("go", label = "Run")
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {

    observeEvent(input$go, {

        session$sendCustomMessage(type='jsCode', 'Shiny.onInputChange("foo", "bar");')

        print(input$foo) # output is NULL

        session$sendCustomMessage(type='jsCode', 'hello();')
        # this does not work either. This is how I originally intended to do this. 
        # By defining a javascript function that aggregates the user selection data and 
        # send it to the server via Shiny.onInputChange

    })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I've seen alternate solutions where an onclick event is bound to the button and then it assigns a random value to some input variable but it seems convoluted to me and I'm not sure why this wouldn't work but that would.

I'm using R version 3.4.3 and shiny_1.0.5. Thanks.

Comment: Replace `eval(message.value)` with `eval(message)` and this works. But `input$foo` will still be `NULL` the first time you click on the button. That's because it takes the `"bar"` value only when shiny exits from the observer.

Comment: Thank you! What you said is true. Is there a way for shiny to assign "bar" to input$foo the first time?

Comment: I think *it is* assigned the first time, but you cannot "detect" it as long as you are in the observer. Try to add `observeEvent(input$foo, {print(input$foo)})`.

Comment: you are right--I can access the value in a nested observeEvent. Thank you, @StéphaneLaurent!!